# SPO CSOM Powershell manage folders with # and % in the name

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, csom

I'm writing a CSOM PS script to create folders in a doclib, and set permissions on them.

Anything works fine except when the folder name contains a %

I am able to create the folder using ResourcePath, FolderCollectionAddParameters and AddUsingPath following [this article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/supporting-and-in-file-and-folder-with-the-resourcepath-api)

But I can't get access to the folder using GetFolderByServerRelativeURL method.

The code is the following :

```
$folderurl="/sites/MySite/MydocLib/MyFolder %1"
$rpFolder = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ResourcePath]::FromDecodedUrl($folderurl)
$CurrentFolder = $ctx.web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl($rpFolder)
$Ctx.Load($CurrentFolder)
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

And I get a "file not found" error.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I found the error : the GetFolderByServerRelativePath method must be used instead of GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl
The right code is :

```
$folderurl="/sites/MySite/MydocLib/MyFolder %1"
$rpFolder = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ResourcePath]::FromDecodedUrl($folderurl)
$CurrentFolder = $ctx.web.GetFolderByServerRelativePath($rpFolder)
$Ctx.Load($CurrentFolder)
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```